# How can I play byte array of audio raw data using NAudio?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, naudio

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
```

Assume `bytes` is an array filled with audio raw data.

How can I play this byte array using a `WaveOut` object?

```
_waveOut.Init(bytes); // <- Error: cannot resolve method.
_waveOut.Play();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured it out, here is the solution:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

IWaveProvider provider = new RawSourceWaveStream(
                         new MemoryStream(bytes), new WaveFormat());

_waveOut.Init(provider);
_waveOut.Play();
```

Comment: when i play  the audio pitch is  ihgher than normal

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer assumes the byte stream is 44,1kHz, 16 bit, stereo. If you have something else you have to provide the coding in the WaveFormat

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

IWaveProvider provider = new RawSourceWaveStream(
                         new MemoryStream(bytes), new WaveFormat(48000, 16, 1));

_waveOut.Init(provider);
_waveOut.Play();
```

If your raw data is in fact a wav file you already have the encoding in the header and can use this method

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(new MemoryStream(bytes));

_waveOut.Init(reader);
_waveOut.Play();
```