# Play audio obtained as byte[] from Azure Speech translation

Tags: azure, .net-core, naudio, azure-cognitive-services

I am following the [samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk) for Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK, namely the [Speech Translation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-translation).

The sample for dotnet core uses microphone as audio input and translates what you speak. Translated results are also available as synthesized speech. I would like to play this audio but could not find the appropriate code for that.

Tried using NAudio as sugguested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28796014/233697) but I get garbled audio. Guess there is more to the format of the audio.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On .Net Core, many audio pacakges might not work. For example with NAudio, I can't play sound on my Mac.

I got it working using `NetCoreAudio` package ([Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetCoreAudio/)), with the following implementation in the translation `Synthesizing` event:

```
recognizer.Synthesizing += (s, e) =>
{
    var audio = e.Result.GetAudio();
    Console.WriteLine(audio.Length != 0
        ? $"AudioSize: {audio.Length}"
        : $"AudioSize: {audio.Length} (end of synthesis data)");

    if (audio.Length > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss.wav")}");
        File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, audio);

        var player = new Player();
        player.Play(fileName).Wait();    
    }
};
```